# How do I convert RGB values to string hex triplet in Julia language

Tags: julia

I am using colors.jl package and have RGB values that I need to convert to hex string triplet value.  What's the best way to do this?  couldn't find a conversion function in colors.jl

thanks

Comment: Does `hex` function do what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom `struct` which is constructible from `AbstractRGB` and which has the appropriate `show` overload as in

```
import Base: show
using ColorTypes

struct RGBPacked
  r::UInt8
  g::UInt8
  b::UInt8

  function (::Type{RGBPacked})(c::AbstractRGB)
    colvec  = (red(c), green(c), blue(c))
    temp    = map(UInt8, map(x->floor(255*x), colvec))
    new(temp[1], temp[2], temp[3])
  end
end

function show(io::IO, r::RGBPacked)
  print(io, "#$(hex(r.r))$(hex(r.g))$(hex(r.b))")
end
```

Then, you can use your custom datatype as in

```
c1 = RGB(1.,0.5,0.7)
c2 = RGBPacked(c1)
```

which prints

```
Main> c1 = RGB(1.,0.5,0.7)
RGB{Float64}(1.0,0.5,0.7)

Main> c2 = RGBPacked(c1)
#ff7fb2
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Bogumil, Colors.jl provides the `hex` function:

```
julia> using Colors

julia> hex(RGB(1,0.5,0))
"FF8000"
```